# How to format a URL within a style tag in Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to do a slideshow effect in Angular, and I have a `div` with a `style` tag (using `ng-style`) with `background-image`.

The URL contains ampersands, and this gives me a `parse:lexerr` error every time.  I've tried with escaping them (&) or directly (&) but it's the same error either way.  The directive looks like this:

```
<div class="responsive-image" ng-style="background-image:url({{service.blobHost}}/{{slides.currentSlide}})">
```

Here are the errors:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 133-133 [&] in expression [background-image:url(https://WWW.HOST.COM/cloud/user-media-32/0604338b-529a-4c42-8f6d-823978327352.jpg?mode=max&scale=both&maxwidth=1280&maxheight=697)].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%20133-133%20%5B%26%5D&p2=background-image%3Aurl(https%3A%2F%2FWWW.HOST.COM%2Fcloud%2Fuser-media-32%2F0604338b-529a-4c42-8f6d-823978327352.jpg%3Fmode%3Dmax%26scale%3Dboth%26maxwidth%3D1280%26maxheight%3D697)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13438:12
    at Lexer.throwError (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27016:11)
    at Lexer.lex (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:26975:16)
    at Object.AST.ast (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27139:30)
    at Object.ASTCompiler.compile (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27592:3


Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 133-133 [&] in expression [background-image:url(https://WWW.HOST.COM/cloud/user-media-32/0604338b-529a-4c42-8f6d-823978327352.jpg?mode=max&scale=both&maxwidth=1280&maxheight=697)].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%20133-133%20%5B%26%5D&p2=background-image%3Aurl(https%3A%2F%2FWWW.HOST.COM%2Fcloud%2Fuser-media-32%2F0604338b-529a-4c42-8f6d-823978327352.jpg%3Fmode%3Dmax%26scale%3Dboth%26maxwidth%3D1280%26maxheight%3D697)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13438:12
    at Lexer.throwError (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27016:11)
    at Lexer.lex (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:26975:16)
    at Object.AST.ast (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27139:30)
    at Object.ASTCompiler.compile (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27592:31)
    at Parser.parse (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:28479:29)
    at $parse (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:28610:39)
    at Scope.$watch (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29823:19)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:42629:9
    at invokeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22993:9)"
```

Am I missing something obvious?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<div class="responsive-image"
    ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + service.blobHost + '/' + slides.currentSlide + ')'}"></div>
```

Here is an example of the filter. The "change slide" will answer your first question (in the comment) that the values will change and the way to apply your filter.

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope, $filter) {

  $scope.service = {
    blobHost: 'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo'
  };

  $scope.slides = {
    currentSlide: '2016/04/19/06/03/mercedes-1338063__340'
  };

  $scope.changeSlide = function() {
    $scope.slides.currentSlide = '2016/07/02/22/42/berries-1493905_640'
  };

  $scope.applyFilter = function(value) {
    return $filter('myFilter')(value)
  }
});

app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(value) {
    return value + '.jpg';
  }
});
```

```css
.responsive-image {
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController">
  <a href="" ng-click="changeSlide()">Change slide</a>
  <br>

  <div class="responsive-image" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + service.blobHost + '/' + applyFilter(slides.currentSlide) + ')'}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will that update when the underlying values update though?  I assumed updateable values need to be in their own double braces.

Comment: Another question:  I need to add a filter to the second expression.  It would have been {{slides.currentSlide|myFilter}}.  How does it look using the single-brace syntax?

Comment: I hadn't actually tried when I wrote the reply.  It works just fine though!  Thanks also for you updates for the filter.  I don't like the change to the more imperative model this way.  The original way I was doing it seems much more logical.  Is there no simple way to just escape the ampersands so Angular doesn't complain?  If not, your approach works perfect.  Thanks so much for your help!